# Deferring removal of a view so it can be animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Say I have a template which displays a view based on a property:

```
{{#if App.contentsAreVisible}}
    {{view ToggleContents}}
{{/if}}
```

This area is toggled by any number of other parts of the UI by setting `App.set("contentsAreVisible", [true/false]);`

This all works fine.

However, I now want to animate when the view is toggled. Hooking into `didInsertElement` works to animate showing the area, but I can't do the same in `willDestroyElement` because the element is removed as soon as that function returns, before the animation has a chance to run.

```
App.ToggleContents = Ember.View.extend({

    // this works fine
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().hide().show("slow");
    },

    // this doesn't work
    willDestroyElement: function(){
        this.$().hide("slow", function(){
            // animation is complete, notify that the element can be removed
        });
    }
});
```

Is there any way to tell the view to defer removing the element from the DOM until the animation is complete?

Here's a fiddle with an interactive example: http://jsfiddle.net/rlivsey/RxxPU/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `hide` function on your view which removes the view when the callback is finished, see http://jsfiddle.net/7EuSC/

**Handlebars**:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="tmpl" >
    <button {{action "hide" }}>hide</button>

    This is my test view which is faded in and out
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```
Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'tmpl',

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().hide().show("slow");
    },

    _hideViewChanged: function() {
        if (this.get('hideView')) {
            this.hide();
        }
    }.observes('hideView'),

    hide: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.$().hide("slow", function() {
            that.remove();
        });
    }
}).append();​
```

Comment: The _hideViewChanged method doesn't really do much to solve the problem at hand, does it?

Comment: It's there for the case where you'd want to hide the view programmatically by setting `hideView`to `true` ...

Comment: And what about the case where hiding is not triggered by an action on a button? Consider the case where I'm showing a list of items, and the list changed because an element is removed. Handlerbars will take care of updating the UI, but by abruptly remove the corresponding view. How can I bypass handlebar's abrupt removal and do it with a fade out?

Comment: @Ernesto, this is my case as well. Did you have any luck fading out on the elements' deletion from the list?

Comment: @Ernesto @pangratz also my use case: sitting in `posts/post1`, `transitionTo('posts')` and want to fade out the currently showing post

Comment: Here is @machty's emberdump about fading out on deletion http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFZ-b3pEK_Y

Answer (score 1):

I know this already has the right answer, but I thought I'd pop something similar up in case anyone else finds this through Google like I did.

One of my apps has a 'detail' section that always has the same content binding but changes the template for view/edit/etc modes.

Because I'm using rerender() to achieve this and want the view to fade out then in again so it hides any glitchiness of the rerender function (as well as make it look nice) I have wrapped it in a  for animation purposes.

```
<script>
_templateChanged: function(){
  self = this;
  $('#effects-wrapper').fadeOut('fast',function(){
    self.rerender();
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
  });            
}.observes('template')
</script>
```

and

```
<div id="effects-wrapper">
{{App.Views.Whatever}}
</div>
```

Perhaps not the best option, but also perhaps useful to someone

Comment: Instead of referencing the view by id (`$('#effects-wrapper')`), you could make this code more robust by using the view's `$()` method, which always refers to the view's DOM element.