# Ember Views, Handlebars and jQuery Effects

Tags: ember.js

I would like to incorporate jQuery effects (fadeIn, fadeOut, etc...) in parts of my handlebar templates. I think that this can more or less be accomplished with a separate view in which the view's `isVisible` property is initially false and its `didInsertElement` method calls something like `this.$().fadeIn()`.

However, what I'd like to do is add a jQuery effect to just a small part of a view - say for purposes of displaying a small block of content that is initially hidden by an `{{#if}}` statement that evaluates to `false` and later through user feedback gets toggled to `true`.  See the following http://jsfiddle.net/YeGbF/2/.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a hint: you may use `toggleProperty` instead of `set('x', !get('x'))`...

Comment: I appreciate that. Can't believe I never noticed that before on Ember.Observable.

Comment: There are also `incrementProperty` and `decrementProperty` on `Ember.Observable`, see http://code418.com/blog/2012/03/31/useful-observable-functions/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a view for the stuff which shall be shown faded in, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/dJMwC/

**Handlebars**:

```html
{{#view App.FadeInView contentBinding="this"}}
    <div>{{content.someAdditionalDetail}}</div>
{{/view}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.FadeInView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function(){
        this.$().hide().show('slow');
    }
});
```

Also have a look at [Deferring removal of a view so it can be animated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9925171/65542)