# Animate view states in State Manager

Tags: ember.js

I have a State Manager implementation with 2 view states. I want to defer the normal removal of a state and add a custom animation when the view is being destroyed and State Manager is transitioning to another state.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xkg6X/

For some reason, hide function of each view state is not being triggered where I can create a custom animation for removal.

Reference: [Deferring removal of a view so it can be animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925171/deferring-removal-of-a-view-so-it-can-be-animated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't ever call the hide function, so it's not going to get executed.

You can use the async transition feature of the state manager to achieve what you're trying to do. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xkg6X/1/

Comment: Oops, my bad. But your comment on async transition feature of state manager is intriguing. Unfortunately, not in the docs. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/831

Comment: There is a pull request that documents this here: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/831

Comment: It looks like async transitions have been removed. Can you illustrate how you could accomplish this with transitional states?