# Animated view transitions

Tags: model-view-controller, animation, ember.js

Suppose I have several views where only one can be shown on the screen at any given time. Is it possible to smoothly change between these views via a carousel-like animation or basic fade-in/fade-out?

I've found this link, but it seems that the functionality describe there had been removed in the latest version of Em.

[Animate view states in State Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854438/animate-view-states-in-state-manager)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [carousel](http://jsfiddle.net/ryDWR/1/) I made using latest EmberJS, I used `Ember.ContainerView` with `currentViewBinding` to achieve this, I am not much into jquery transitions, though I added transitions at entry, If you can add a transitions while exiting this'd be complete 
More documentation on [Ember.ContainerView](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-pre.2/packages/ember-views/lib/views/container_view.js#L15) you may look at `_currentViewWillChange` or `childViewsWillChange` method in order to add exit transitions

Comment: Looks perfect, though it seems to regenerate the view each time it shown, which is not exactly what I want.

Comment: hmm...but if you want to play smooth with views in ember ContainerView is a great starting point, it's upto you how you implement it, i just showed you one of the possible ways

Comment: @NewlessClubie this just answered my question about animated transitions. You should consider accepting it as an answer.